# Linux kill `screen` after idle 900 instead of locking screen

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, terminal

Is there a way to kill the current `screen` session if the user has been idle for 15mins. I know you can edit the `screenrc` file and add `idle 900 lockscreen` however, this only locks the screen not killing the current screen session disconnecting the user.

(any other method for disconnecting the user after 15mins welcome. `TMOUT` and `ClientAliveInterval` wont disconnect users who are running commands like vim/htop/sleep 1000 so cant be used for this.)

This forms a part of the PCI DSS compliance framework so im interested in knowing how others get around this requirement properly but it seems everyone is using `TMOUT` that doesn't fully meet the specs of whats needed.

Answer (score -1):

Using `screen`, you can use `idle 900 kill` in your `screenrc` file.